# Magento 2 Checkout - Rename label

Tags: magento2

I want to rename the label Shipping Address on checkout page, have searched for it and tried the solutions but didn't success.
Please guide me in this,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename through the translation files vendor/magento/module-checkout/i18n/en_US.csv

change "Shipping Address", "Shipping Address" to anything you like
"Shipping Address", "Change to me"

Comment: Do this file need to override in theme folder?

Comment: Well, not working for me